# Meaning of notation $\{x,y\}\subset A$ in a partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently came across this notation:
$$\{x,y\}\subset A$$
Where $A\in \mathbb{A}$, and $\mathbb{A}$ is a partition of a non-empty set X.

Does it mean that $x,y\in A$? Isn't $A$ a set of elements and not a set of sets?

Could someone clarify the meaning of $\{x,y\}\subset A$?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: $B \subset A$ means that all the elements of $B$ are elements of $A$.

Comment: $B\subseteq A\iff \left(a\in B\,\Rightarrow\, a\in A\right)$ for an arbitrary object $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $\{x,y\}\subset A$ has its usual meaning here: $\{x,y\}$ is a subset of $A$, so $x,y\in A$. This makes perfectly good sense: $A$ is an element of a partition of $X$, so $A\subseteq X$, and therefore $x$ and $y$ are elements of $X$.

Comment: I thought $\{x,y\}\subset A$ would imply that $A=\{\{x,y\},...\}$ (a set of sets).

Comment: @Guilherme: No, that would mean that $\{x,y\}\in A$, that the set $\{x,y\}$ is an *element* of $A$ rather than a *subset* of $A$.

Comment: Oh! Indeed! Thanks!

Comment: @Guilherme: You’re welcome!